# Angular Material layouts demo isn't working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm trying to just run the Angular Material grid layouts demo that can be found [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/grid) titled Flex Percent Values.

Excerpts from my HTML code is as follows:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
  <!-- LINK TO LOCAL BUT HOW? -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0-rc4/angular-material.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../bower_components/angular-material/modules/css/angular-material-layouts.css">
  <base href="/">
</head>
<body data-ng-app="MyApp" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div layout="row" layout-wrap>
      <div flex="30">
        [flex="30"]
      </div>
      <div flex="45">
        [flex="45"]
      </div>
      <div flex="25">
        [flex="25"]
      </div>
      <div flex="33">
        [flex="33"]
      </div>
      <div flex="66">
        [flex="66"]
      </div>
      <div flex="50">
        [flex="50"]
      </div>
      <div flex>
        [flex]
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
<!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 0.11.2 used here -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.js"></script>
```

When I add Material Angular elements like `md-button` they render, although anything layout related doesn't work. I've double checked that I'm importing all the stylesheets I need, and I think I am. I'm not sure what's wrong though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're linking to the CSS stylesheet of the 1.0.0-rc4 version but you're loading the scripts of the 0.11.2 version...

I'm pretty sure that this is the problem!